# How to get notifications list in recyclerview, UI?

Tags: android

I have a list on new notifications saved in room in ViewModel I have variable:

```
    val test = MutableStateFlow<List<ItemsResponse.ItemData>>(emptyList())
```

In adapter I have misunderstanding right now I try to also bind it with another UIModel

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotificationItemViewHolder, position: Int) =
        with(holder) {
            bind(item)
            setOnClickListener { onItemClicked(item.id) }
            
            //(item) is on red, error I don't have such variable to use here.
        }

[...]

    class ItemViewHolder(private val layout: LayoutListItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layout.root) {
        fun bind(item: ItemUIModel) = with(layout) {
            tvName.text = item.Name
            tvProduct.text = item.product
            tvSimpleText.text = item.simpleText
            tvInformation.text = item.information
            tvTime.text = item.time
            tvData.text = item.data
        }
```

In my fragment I can get this data and it log a list.

```
        vm.test.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner){
            Log.d("TEST", "test message $it")

        }
```

I have just lost a little bit could you guys help me just with this case?
How to implement onBindViewHolder correctly and how to in the fragment display this data in the UI?

EDIT:
My new NotificationAdapter

```
class NotificationAdapter(diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<NotificationItemUIModel> = NotificationUIItemComparator) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationItemViewHolder>() {
    private var onItemClicked: (Int) -> Unit = {}
    var items = emptyList<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotificationItemViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return LayoutListItemNotificationBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
            .let(::NotificationItemViewHolder)
        setListData(items)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotificationItemViewHolder, position: Int) =
        with(holder) {
        bind(items[position])

            //bind(items[position]) error Type mismatch.
    }

    class NotificationItemViewHolder(private val layout: LayoutListItemNotificationBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layout.root) {
        fun bind(item: NotificationItemUIModel) = with(layout) {
            tvName.text = item.Name
            tvProductNotification.text = item.product
            tvSimpleText.text = item.simpleText
            tvInformation.text = item.information
            tvTime.text = item.time
            tvData.text = item.data
        }

    object NotificationUIItemComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<NotificationItemUIModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: NotificationItemUIModel,
            newItem: NotificationItemUIModel
        ) = oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: NotificationItemUIModel,
            newItem: NotificationItemUIModel
        ) = oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    fun setListData(list: List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>) {
        this.items = list

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

```
data class NotificationItemsResponse(
    val notifications: List<NotificationItemData>,
    @SerializedName("lastPage")
        val isLastPage: Boolean
) {
    @Entity(tableName = "notification_list")
    data class NotificationItemData(
        val name: String,
        val product: String,
        val data: String,
        val time: String
    ){
        @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int = 0
    }
}
```

```
data class NotificationItemUIModel(
    val id: Int,
    val leadFullName: String,
    val information: String,
    val product: String,
    val simpleText: String,
    val data: String,
    val time: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapter

```
var data = List<ItemsResponse.ItemData>
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotificationItemViewHolder, 
    position: Int) =
        with(holder) {
            bind(data[position])
              ....
        }
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return data.size
}
```

fragment

```
vm.test.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner){
   adapter.data = it
}
```

Comment: I cannot use:
it needs function invocation:

Now I have my
    var items = emptyList<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>()

OnCreateViewHOlder {
        setListData(items)
}
[...]
    fun setListData(list: List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>) {
        this.items = list

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

Fragment is alright.

I will give my my whole NotificationAdapter main post: EDIT

I do not know what is (value) in your code and field.
Is it just:
        this.items = list
?

Comment: I can't understand what is the display data? `NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData` or `NotificationItemUIModel`

Comment: NotificationItemData, data class for room

UIModel just simple data class with the same or similar values
It could be implemented without this ItemUIModel

Edit main post

Comment: edit your `NotificationItemViewHolder bind(item : NotificationItemData)` bacause you want to display NotificationItemData. UIModel  and NotificationItemData are not related.